# lvm, one vol mounted at /dev/mapper, one at /dev

Tags: lvm

I have created a volume group `webserver` with volumes `home` and `usr`

They were created identically, in `/etc/fstab` listed
as

```
/dev/webserver/home    /home  /ext4   rw,noatime   0 0
/dev/webserver/usr     /usr   /ext4   rw,noatime   0 0
```

However, `mount` shows them as

```
/dev/mapper/webserver-usr on /usr
/dev/mapper/webserver-home on /home
```

and `df` as

```
/dev/webserver/usr   999 999 999 99% /usr
/dev/mapper/webserver-home 999 999 999 99% /home
```

(not real numbers, can't copy/paste and numbers are not relevant anyway)

Why is `mapper` shown some places and not others?

It seems to be working perfectly fine anyway, just confused about the differences.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `/usr` (or `/`) and `/home` usually is that the rootfs (including `/usr`) has to be mounted early at boot. This is done by initramfs.

On the other hand `/home`, `/var/www`, and other regular partitions you might have, should be mounted later, outside of initramfs, in the course of the regular boot process by the full init system.

So the behavior in mounting can be different in some details.

For example, on my system, the rootfs shows up as `/dev/dm-34` instead of `/dev/SSD/root` or `/dev/mapper/SSD-root`. That's simply because the partition is identified by UUID, and the `findfs` utility is just implemented differently in initramfs / busybox vs. full system / util-linux:

```
# busybox findfs UUID=fa15678f-7e7e-4a47-8ed2-7cea7a5d037d
/dev/dm-34
# findfs UUID=fa15678f-7e7e-4a47-8ed2-7cea7a5d037d
/dev/mapper/SSD-root
```

This command might just as well return `/dev/SSD/root`, depending on how `/dev` was populated with device names vs. symlinks. After changing symlink direction `/dev/SSD/root -> /dev/mapper/SSD-root` to `/dev/mapper/SSD-root -> /dev/SSD/root`, the result is identical:

```
# busybox findfs UUID="fa15678f-7e7e-4a47-8ed2-7cea7a5d037d"
/dev/SSD/root
# findfs UUID="fa15678f-7e7e-4a47-8ed2-7cea7a5d037d"
/dev/SSD/root
```

I haven't looked at the code how it decides which name to pick as the canonical one.

In the end it doesn't really matter, as long as the correct filesystem is mounted, this is at most a cosmetical issue.

Comment: Having discovered the magic of lvm, is it possible to convert a partition to lvm without copying the data? Especially the root...

Comment: @Lenne there's `lvmify` or manual process described https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/Howto/LVM_nachträglich_einrichten/ (in German). In-place conversions always come with a risk, so if your LVM isn't full, copying might be preferable actually.